# How to vertically align Qlistwidgetitem text with the icon?

Tags: qt

I'm adding icons and text as Qlistwidgetitem in Qlistwidget.
icon size is 24*24, and it is on the left of the text. After adding the icon, text appears to be on the top of the available space, I want to align it vertically in the available space.
I tried `itemToAdd->setTextAlignment( Qt::AlignVCenter)` but it is not showing any effect.

Could you suggest any other method to do it?

[image]

See text are at the top of available space.

`myQlistWidget->addItem(new QListWidgetItem( *GuiIconManager::ref().find("icon") , nodeValue()) );`

*GuiIconManager::ref().find("icon") returns QIcon size of 24*24 and nodeValue() returns QString.

OS is linux.

Comment: What's your runtime OS? I test in Windows 7 and it [looks fine](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/92784443/exp.png). 
Did you use designer or handcrafted all codes? If it was the later, please show us more details about your codes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Tay2510.
I didn't use designer, I handcrafted the code.
Its 
myQlistWidget->addItem(new QListWidgetItem(  *GuiIconManager::ref().find("icon") , nodeValue()) );

*GuiIconManager::ref().find("icon") returns QIcon size of 24*24 
and nodeValue() returns QString.

OS is linux.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the string you're passing into QListWidgetItem doesn't have a newline at the end of it